# AWK command not able to parse out any fields

Tags: awk

i have the following file:

```
Identifier@Unit@Program@Name
a031fVzAAJ@aT1r6AAC@DR003@OPA
a0300fVzAAJ@a20T1r6AAC@DR3003@OPA
```

When i use

```
awk -F'@' '{print $1}' filename
```

I just get the output:

```
??I
```

I'm not sure what's happening here! I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Some things to check:

(1) Is the input file pure ASCII? Run `hexdump -C filename` to check
(2) Any encoding problems? Check $LANG, $LC_ALL
(3) What version of Awk are you using? Is it GNU Awk? (a.k.a. gawk)

Comment: Are you using the correct file? I just tried and it returns "Identifier"

Comment: assuming your data is in a file, it is probably MS-Windows line-endings causing thiss problem, i.e. `\r\n`. Clean them up with `dos2unix myFile.txt` Good luck.

Comment: awk -F"@" '{print $1}' file

Comment: there's garbage in your file. do `cat -v filename` to see it.

Comment: Depending on the garbage in your file, you might be able to do `strings filename |awk -F@ '{print $1}' filename`.  Otherwise, perhaps try `sed 's/@.*//g' filename` or `strings filename |sed 's/@.*//g'`